Does transforming a periodic function imply periodicity
Let $f(x,y)$ be a periodic function for every fixed $y = \beta$ with respect to $x$ in the domain $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and consider this transform of $f$:
\begin{equation}
f^\star(\alpha,\beta ) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{f(\beta,n)}{n^{\alpha}}}
\end{equation}
is $f^\star$ also periodic? For example when f(x,y) is $\cos(y\ln(x))$. In this situation it seems we are adding a bunch of cosine waves that are dampening in magnitude to produce maybe another larger wave (if the sum of waves was to produce another wave) which I believe happens because there is a value $c$ and $d$ such that we can write $$\cos(ax)+\cos(bx) =cos(cx)/d$$ for all a,b.

just try $f(x,y)=\cos(x\sqrt{y})$, the resulting $f^\star(\alpha,\beta)$ is not periodic in $\beta$ for any fixed $\alpha$

How do you know it's not periodic. Your still adding a bunch of cosine functions in the series each term is then $\cos(\beta \sqrt{n})/n^\alpha $

@carlo using this function we get $$f^*(x,y)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{\cos(y,\sqrt{n})}{n^x}} = \cos(y\sqrt{1})/1^x+\cos(y\sqrt{2})/2^x +.... $$ if I'm not mistaken which is kinda like a cosine in $y$

I have worked out a simple counterexample.

A simple counterexample:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\cos(x\sqrt{y})&\text{for}\;1\leq y\leq 2,\\
\text{arbitrary}&\text{for}\; 2<y<3,\\
0&\text{for}\;y\geq 3,
\end{cases}$$
$$\Rightarrow f^\star(0,\beta)=\cos \beta + \cos(\beta\sqrt{2})=2\cos[\tfrac{1}{2}\beta(\sqrt{2}+1)]\cos[\tfrac{1}{2}\beta(\sqrt{2}-1)]$$
is not periodic in $\beta$ because the frequencies of the two cosine factors are incommensurate.

Thanks @carlo so the periodicity is not really preserved I guess. Maybe it is for certain function like the one that matches the zeta function. It appears maybe "most" the time it is period. Does it not appear we are balancing a bunch of waves?

Like maybe non zero functions for all $y$

If we add two waves we should get another wave if the periods don't match or are different. This is why my intuition wants to lean this way

the zeta function is not periodic because it is a sum of an alternating series of periodic functions with incommensurate frequencies: $\eta(s)=-\sum_n (-1)^n e^{-s\ln n}$ and $\ln 2$, $\ln 3$, $\ln 5$, ... are incommensurate

But it has been shown that the zeroes are periodic (if they exist) this both can't be true

For each $y$ you can find a $y^'$ such that $\zeta(1/2+yi)=\zeta(1/2+y^' I)$ so $\zeta$ repeats itself many times and equates to zero many times along the half point. If it's not periodic then how can this happen

Don't know why my zeta not reading correctly

having an infinite sequence of zeroes is not the same as having a periodic function, the spacing of the zeroes is not constant.

Periodic just means that the functions equals itself many times not that space is constant

this is really confusing; you would call the Bessel function $J_0(x)$ a periodic function?

Yes any function that repeats itself infinity times or throughout it's domain

Would you say $\cos(1/x)$ is periodic ?

It's pretty clear my definition is screwed a bit but if we take the definition to mean that the function just equals itself not at constant rates then this should produce a contradiction if zeta is not periodic
